# How to solve T(n) = 5T(n/2) + n^2, T(1) = 2 recursively

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

How to fond the asymptotic upper bound for T(n) = 5T(n/2) + n^2, T(1) = 2 without using master theorem.

Here are my steps, but I don't know how to deal with the summation at the end and thus cannot find the big-O answer for this recursion function.

```
T(n) = 5T(n/2) + n^2
     = 5^2 T(n/2^2) + 5(n/2)^2 + n^2
     = 5^3 T(n/2^3) + 5^2(n/2^2)^2 + 5(n/2)^2 + n^2
     = ...
     = 5^i T(n/2^i) + 5^i(n/2^i)^2 + ...+ 5^2(n/2^2)^2 + 5(n/2)^2 + n^2
     = 5^i T(n/2^i) + n^2 Sum of k from 0 to i, (5/4)^k
```

How to deal with the summation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to deal with the summation?

What you describe here in the sum is a [*geometric progression* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series). Such sum of the form:

```
 n
---
\     i
/    a
---
i=0
```

has a known solution:

```
 n
---           n+1
\     i      a    - 1
/    a     = --------
---            a - 1
i=0
```

So here your sum:

> Sum of k from 0 to i, (5/4)^k

is equal to:

```
4 * ((5/4)^(i+1) - 1)
```

We know that `i` is limited to *log<sub>2</sub>n*, and this should be sufficient to solve the equation.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought "a" should be between 0 and 1 in order to use that equation. Yet, in this case, "a" is 5/4 which we cannot use that equation for finding the sum.

Comment: @JustABadProgrammer: no, that is a condition given you want the *infinite* sum, that makes sense since if *a >= 1*, then that sum will only grow bigger, and thus result in infinity, but if you have a *bound* for the "iterator", then this works, regardless of the *a*, as is also written on the wiki page. You can test it with a given `a` (like 5/4) and a given `n` (like 3). Then we get  4 * (((5 / 4) ^ 4) - 1) = 5.765625, which is indeed 1 + 5/4 + 25/16 + 125/64.